# MacBook Pro keyboard replacement: Refurbished or new components?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, battery

I'm about to send my 2016 MacBook Pro for a top case replacement due to a failing keyboard. Since the battery will also be replaced as a part of the top case, I'm wondering if Apple installs a refurbished battery or a brand new one? And for that matter, is there any way to really tell?

Answer (score 0):

Batteries are never refurbished and installed brand new. The usage status of a battery can be determined by looking at the consumed charge cycles (1 full charge and discharge constitute 1 charge cycle).

You can easily determine the battery charge cycles consumed by going to  → About This Mac → System Report... → Hardware → Power → Battery Information → Health Information → Cycle Count. It should look something like this:

[image]

There's also an excellent 3rd party tool called [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) which is very easy to use.